# MySQL - INSERT INTO … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with values select from the same table

Tags: mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I have two tables, one is `posts(ID, edited_date, is_public, ... etc)`, another one is `post_pagination(index, post_id)` for storing the pagination data of posts. In `post_pagination`, `index` is primary key.

One step in the pagination process, I need to check the sorted result and `post_pagination` table, and do INSERT/UPDATE, like:

```
INSERT INTO post_pagination(`index`, post_id)
SELECT * /* full outer join new sorted result and pagination table */
FROM (
    WITH 
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY edited_date DESC, ID DESC) AS new_rank, ID
        FROM posts
        WHERE is_public = 1
    ),
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT `index`
        FROM post_pagination
    )
    SELECT `index` AS dummy_rank, ID
    FROM cte2
    LEFT JOIN cte1 on `index` = new_rank
    UNION ALL
    SELECT new_rank AS dummy_rank, ID
    FROM cte2
    RIGHT JOIN cte1 on `index` = new_rank
    WHERE `index` IS NULL
) AS a
ORDER BY dummy_rank
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_id = ID
```

The first time run this query, `post_pagination` is empty, so MySQL insert all data into the table.

```
index  post_id
1      390
2      391
3      392
4      393
5      307
```

it works well.

When I run the second time, I expect all data will not be changed, but it update all `post_id` field to the last value of the result.

```
index  post_id
1      307
2      307
3      307
4      307
5      307
```

I did a few tests, it seems like inserting values into a table by using values select from the same table would cause this problem, but I can't figure out why

Now I simply fix this problem by modifying the last line of the query to:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_id = ID + 0
```

Is there any better way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you instead use a temporary table?

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `post_pagination_temp` (
 `index` INTEGER(1) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `post_id` INTEGER(1)
);

INSERT INTO `post_pagination_temp` (`post_id`)
SELECT `ID` FROM `posts` ORDER BY `edited_date` DESC, `ID` DESC;

INSERT INTO `post_pagination`
SELECT * FROM `post_pagination_temp`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `index` = VALUES(`index`);
```

This assumes you have the correct index on `post_pagination`, i.e. the only unique being the primary key on `post_id`.